# I am connected to firebae project correctly still ".info/connected" always returns false , I also have good internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am checking state of my connection and it always retuns connection failed what should I do, can anyone suggest a solution

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (!connected) {
                Toast.makeText(secrect_inside_chat.this, "connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(secrect_inside_chat.this, "not connected" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: If `.info/connected` is false, it means that the client is not connected to the Firebase Database serves. To find out why, it might help to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and study the output/

Comment: so it was working fine few days ago and now it just got disconnected by itself ?

Comment: My notifications are showing Your Cloud Firestore database will start denying client requests unless you update your security rules, but I'm using real-time database is their any connection between two?

Comment: I gave explicit instructions in my comment on what to do. If you did that and can't make sense of the logging output, include the logging output in your question and I'll have a look. Note that you can determine the **relevant** logging output by comparing the output from starting your app without the Firebase debug logging, with the output after you enable it.